# fetch как обработать исключение 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, try-catch, fetch

Использую вот такой код:

```
try {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => callback(data))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Намерено ставлю неверный `url` и одно исключение успешно отлавливаю с помощью `.catch(e => console.log(e))`, но есть вот такое не обработанное исключение:

`GET https://neto-api.herokuapp.com/ets 404 (Not Found)`

Как его обработать? `try..catch` почему-то не срабатывает

Comment: никак, это вывод от самого запроса

Comment: Понял. Это грустно

Comment: нет смысла писать .then(data => callback(data)), можно просто написать .then(callback), Даже можно вот так писать .catch(console.log); Но так не делай, по тому что в консоль не выведет место от куда ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try catch не работает потому что fetch асинхронный..
Зато у промисов встроенный catch есть.

Но даже если ты словишь и обработаешь ошибку 404, ругань в консоль все-равно полетит(

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(resp => {
        if (!resp.ok) {
            throw Error(`is not ok: ` + resp.status);
        }
    return resp.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    })
```

Либо так:

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(resp => (resp.ok)
        ? resp.json()
        : Promise.reject('is not ok: ' + resp.status)
    )
    .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    })
```

Comment: А как избавиться от ошибки 404 в консоли?